# Editing name of the activity in XML file

Tags: android, android-activity, android-applicationinfo

The Android Activities name is to be changed. In which XML file can I find the attribute. I didn't find it in Activities corresponding XML file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You are adding an Activity in `Androidmanifest.xml` file you can set  `android:label="@string/app_name_main"` for every activity..
For every activity you can set this.

For eg:

```
           <activity
            android:name="com.example.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

            <activity
            android:name="com.example.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name2"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

            <activity
            android:name="com.example.ThirdActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name3"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you search for is:

```
setTitle("new name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the action bar title which looks like application label using below code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
```

Each activity must extends ActionBarActivity/AppBarActivity/FragmentActivity to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for changing application label, which is not possible .Because it is a fixed string in the AndroidManifest.xml file which cannot be changed at run-time.

If you are looking for `Activity` title change, you can set the title of activity by calling 'setTitle("your_title")' in your `Activity`